# Python LinkedList implementation and tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I'm implementing some basic data structures in Python. How does my LinkedList look like? 
My experience in testing is quite low and I would really appreciate a review.

Implementation:

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
            self.value = value
            self.next = next_node

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.value == other.value and self.next == other.next


    EMPTY_LIST_ERROR_MSG = 'List is empty!'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = None

    def add_first(self, value):
        """ A -> B -> C -> D -> None
            E -> A -> B -> C -> D -> None"""
        new_node = self.Node(value=value)

        if self.__head:
            new_node.next = self.__head
        self.__head = new_node

    def add_last(self, value):
        """ A -> B -> C -> D -> None
            A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> None"""
        new_node = self.Node(value)
        last_node = None
        for node in self.__node_iter():
            last_node = node

        if last_node:
            last_node.next = new_node
        else:
            self.__head = new_node

    def insert_after(self, item, value):
        """Inserting F after C:
            A -> B -> C -> D -> None
            A -> B -> C -> F -> D -> None"""

        if not self.__head:
            raise IndexError(self.EMPTY_LIST_ERROR_MSG)

        node = self.__head
        while node and node.value != item:
            node = node.next

        if node:
            node_next = node.next
            node.next = self.Node(value, node_next)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'No such item {item}')

    def remove(self, value):
        """ Removing C:
            A -> B -> C -> D -> None
            A -> B -> D -> None"""
        if not self.__head:
            raise IndexError(self.EMPTY_LIST_ERROR_MSG)

        if self.__head.value == value:
            self.remove_first()
        else:
            previous = self.__head
            node = self.__head.next
            while node and node.value != value:
                previous = node
                node = node.next
            if node:
                previous.next = node.next
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'No such value: {value}')

    def remove_first(self):
        """ A -> B -> C -> D -> None
            B -> C -> D -> None"""
        if not self.__head:
            raise IndexError(self.EMPTY_LIST_ERROR_MSG)
        self.__head = self.__head.next

    def remove_last(self):
        """ A -> B -> C -> D -> None
            A -> B -> C -> None"""
        if not self.__head:
            raise IndexError(self.EMPTY_LIST_ERROR_MSG)

        previous = None
        node = self.__head
        while node.next:
            previous = node
            node = node.next
        if previous:
            previous.next = None
        else:
            self.__head = None

    def reverse(self):
        """ A -> B -> C -> D -> None
            D -> C -> B -> A -> None"""
        previous = None
        node = self.__head
        while node:
            node_next = node.next
            node.next = previous
            previous = node
            node = node_next
        self.__head = previous

    def __node_iter(self):
        node = self.__head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def __contains__(self, item):
        for value in self:
            if item == value:
                return True
        return False

    def __len__(self):
        count = 0
        for _ in self:
            count += 1
        return count

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]".format(", ".join(map(str, self)))

    def __iter__(self):
        """:returns values iterator"""
        return iter(map(lambda node: node.value, self.__node_iter()))
```

Tests:

```
import pytest

from linear.linked_list import LinkedList


class TestLinkedList:
    def setup_method(self):
        """[12, 8, 2, 5]"""
        self.prepared_linked_list = LinkedList()
        self.prepared_linked_list.add_first(5)
        self.prepared_linked_list.add_first(2)
        self.prepared_linked_list.add_first(8)
        self.prepared_linked_list.add_first(12)

        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 8, 2, 5]

    def test_add_first(self):
        linked_list = LinkedList()

        linked_list.add_first(1)
        assert list(linked_list) == [1]

        linked_list.add_first(3)
        assert list(linked_list) == [3, 1]

        linked_list.add_first(5)
        assert list(linked_list) == [5, 3, 1]

        linked_list.add_first(4)
        assert list(linked_list) == [4, 5, 3, 1]

    def test_add_last(self):
        linked_list = LinkedList()

        linked_list.add_last(1)
        assert list(linked_list) == [1]

        linked_list.add_last(3)
        assert list(linked_list) == [1, 3]

        linked_list.add_last(5)
        assert list(linked_list) == [1, 3, 5]

        linked_list.add_last(4)
        assert list(linked_list) == [1, 3, 5, 4]

    def test_insert_after(self):
        self.prepared_linked_list.insert_after(2, 4)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 8, 2, 4, 5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.insert_after(2, 3)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.insert_after(12, 1)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.insert_after(5, 50)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 50]

        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            self.prepared_linked_list.insert_after(16, 40)

        linked_list = LinkedList()
        with pytest.raises(IndexError):
            linked_list.insert_after(5, 12)

        linked_list.add_first(3)
        linked_list.insert_after(3, 4)
        assert list(linked_list) == [3, 4]

    def test_remove_first(self):
        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_first()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [8, 2, 5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_first()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [2, 5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_first()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_first()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == []

        with pytest.raises(IndexError):
            self.prepared_linked_list.remove_first()

    def test_remove_last(self):
        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_last()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 8, 2]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_last()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 8]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_last()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_last()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == []

        with pytest.raises(IndexError):
            self.prepared_linked_list.remove_last()

    def test_remove(self):
        self.prepared_linked_list.remove(2)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [12, 8, 5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove(12)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [8, 5]

        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            self.prepared_linked_list.remove(12)

        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [8, 5]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove(5)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [8]

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove(8)
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == []

        with pytest.raises(IndexError):
            self.prepared_linked_list.remove(8)

    def test_reverse(self):
        self.prepared_linked_list.reverse()
        assert list(self.prepared_linked_list) == [5, 2, 8, 12]

        linked_list = LinkedList()
        linked_list.reverse()
        assert list(linked_list) == []

        linked_list.add_first(5)
        linked_list.reverse()
        assert list(linked_list) == [5]

    def test_contains(self):
        assert 12 in self.prepared_linked_list
        assert 2 in self.prepared_linked_list
        assert 5 in self.prepared_linked_list
        assert 8 in self.prepared_linked_list

        assert 11 not in self.prepared_linked_list
        assert 28 not in self.prepared_linked_list

        linked_list = LinkedList()
        assert 5 not in linked_list

        linked_list.add_first(5)
        assert 5 in linked_list

    def test_len(self):
        assert len(self.prepared_linked_list) == 4

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_last()
        assert len(self.prepared_linked_list) == 3

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_first()
        assert len(self.prepared_linked_list) == 2

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_first()
        assert len(self.prepared_linked_list) == 1

        self.prepared_linked_list.remove_last()
        assert len(self.prepared_linked_list) == 0

    def test_iter(self):
        assert next(iter(self.prepared_linked_list)) == 12

        iterator = iter(self.prepared_linked_list)
        assert next(iterator) == 12
        assert next(iterator) == 8
        assert next(iterator) == 2
        assert next(iterator) == 5
        with pytest.raises(StopIteration):
            next(iterator)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the first code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error constants

There's less value in doing this:

```
EMPTY_LIST_ERROR_MSG = 'List is empty!'
```

and passing it like

```
        raise IndexError(self.EMPTY_LIST_ERROR_MSG)
```

into a built-in exception. There's more value in making an exception type of your own, maybe derived from `IndexError`. I don't think it's really worth externalizing such strings into constants unless

1. the string constant is very long;
2. the string constant's purpose cannot be understood by looking at its contents alone; or
3. you care about i18n.

### Cascading comparison

Are you sure that this:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value and self.next == other.next
```

does what you want? I believe that, as written, due to the reference to `next` it will cascade to comparing every single value in the list after the current one. This is not likely what you want. If all you want to do is check whether `next` is the same *reference* without a cascaded equality comparison, then use `is` instead of `==`.

### Private variables

Use `self._head` instead of `self.__head`, which has a different meaning.

### Method names

Consider attempting to match Python's built-in collection terminology, i.e. [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of `remove_last`. A more useful interface would do what `pop` does and return the removed item as well.

### Predicate generators

```
    for value in self:
        if item == value:
            return True
    return False
```

can be

```
return any(item == value for value in self)
```

Also,

```
    count = 0
    for _ in self:
        count += 1
    return count
```

can be

```
return sum(1 for _ in self)
```